# File read from C++ doesn't work but it works in JAVA in android. Why?

Tags: java, android, c++, filesystems

I'm trying to access files in native code in Android like this:

```
// native_model_path = /storage/emulated/0/Model
std::ifstream file(std::string(native_model_path).append("/ex_file.weights"));
if ((file.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit) != 0) {
    printf("Not able to open file");
    return;
}
```

This prints `Not able to open file`. But the same file is getting opened in JAVA without any issues. I'm opening it like this:

```
String storage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
if (!CheckFiles(inPath) ||
    !CheckFiles(storage + File.separator + "Model/", "ex_file.cfg") ||
    !CheckFiles(storage + File.separator + "Model/", "ex_file.weights")) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Either the input file path or model files path is invalid! Abort.");
    return;
}
```

This passes.

My `minSdkVersion 23` and `targetSdkVersion 30`. I have set permissions in manifest file too. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`. Still not able to access the files in native code. Am I missing something? Please reply.

Comment: Note that `(file.rdstate() & std::ifstream::failbit) != 0)` is equivalent to just `file.fail()` or you could even just use `if (file)` (which isn't exactly the same but checks whether the steam is `good` which is what you want)

Comment: Haven't there recently been even further restrictions on the storage that native code can access?